# When to expect a *kn*

Tags: names, phonetics, surnames

Here is a personally inspired question, but I hope it finds broader relevance.

### Without clear specific roots, what phonetically indicates that a word is spelled with a *kn* rather than an *n*?

Recently a friend and I were discussing his name, which begins with an *N*.† As it is uncommon, most people that hear it don't know its origins or how it is spelled. Almost invariably when they first try to spell it they assume it begins with a *K*.

**What makes them assume this?**

I am interested in both inherent and applied indicators.

- Is there a slight difference in pronunciation of *kn-* and *n-*, and my friend employs the former?
- The name is of Slavic origins and I, though maybe biased by the truth, hear nothing Germanic in it; nonetheless, could some Germanic-seeming traits encourage hearers to think it's Germanic, and thus potentially take a *kn-*? I don't trust that everyone that assumes the *k* is linguistically aware to associate *kn* with Germanic languages, so this would be at a deeper level of language understanding.

†*If this question proves impossible without giving the actual name I will ask my friend for approval to divulge, but for now I want to respect his privacy.*

Comment: This question references Germanic and Slavic languages but the interactions and assumptions are happening in the context of English, so I therefore find it relevant for the site.

Comment: My immediate guess is that the name sounds like a word that we already know starts with a *kn-*.  If you're named "Night", "Notts", "Nox", or "Nuckel", for example.

Comment: There is no difference in pronunciation between 'night' and 'knight', and the like. Without knowing your friend's name it's impossible to suggest a reason.